# Angular 6- maintain page load after authentication from third party server

Tags: routes, angular6

I am facing issue related to maintain current page on reload.

My application authenticate user from third party web site. If user is not authorize  it will redirect to   third party site after successful authentication server redirect to my application but  if i request from this url
 **http://localhost:4200/#/pages/abc** or press F5 for refresh page my  application show me home page  **http://localhost:4200/#/pages/home** instead of that page .

Please help me  to maintain current page instead of home page load.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't shared the code. So to imagine your workflow is quite difficult.

One guess, is that you have some router guard, which is redirecting to home page.